# Insert mutiple rigged characters as a crowd

Tags: rigging

I have a soccer stadium and id like to insert a crowd. I have rigged maximo assets. Theres 45k seats lol whats the best quickest way to insert? So far i can only add via duplicate onto an empty and continually doing so. With 45k seats that wud take me years

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at http://crowdmaster.org/. I haven't used it myself but it seems to have been used by some established blender studios so is likely to be reasonable.